# Show that it has no feasible solution.

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, two-phase-simplex

An optimization problem:

$$\text{ maximize  } z=8x+6y$$
$$\text{ such that:  } x-y ≤ 0.6 \text{ and  } x-y≥2$$

Show that it has no feasible solution using **SIMPLEX METHOD**.

It seems very logical that it has no feasible solution(how can a value be less than $0.6$ and greater than $2$ at the same time). 
When I tried solving it using simplex method, I found that it has an unbounded solution(as corresponding to the maximum(positive) value of $c_j − z_j $, all values in the corresponding column were either negative or zero).

Comment: The region is empty, as you point out.  There are no values of $z$ to consider.

Comment: maximize $z$ over the empty set :P

Comment: @lulu  can you please prove it through simplex method ?

Comment: use the Two-Phases Simplex Algorithm

Comment: Can you learn from [this solved problem](http://www.universalteacherpublications.com/univ/ebooks/or/Ch3/no-feasible-solution.htm) and show us where you got stuck?  If you can solve this problem after reading this, you may answer your own question and accept it, so that we can upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

you will get $$2\le x-y\le \frac{3}{5}$$ which is impossible.

Comment: That's not the [way to show infeasible solution using Simplex Algorithm](http://www.universalteacherpublications.com/univ/ebooks/or/Ch3/no-feasible-solution.htm).